# Which text describes 16th secret syllable of sri vidya?

Tags: sri-vidya

Shodashi has 16 syllables. Which text describes it and how is this mantra different in effects from 15 letter one ?

Comment: There are many such texts.

Comment: Any text describing difference in effects of 15 n 16 letter mantra ?

Comment: Most texts describe the effect of chanting the Shodashi Vidya. Very few texts describe the same for Panchadashi.

Comment: Can u point to any text online that can be read in this regard. Thanks

Comment: In [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27478/whats-the-chanting-benefits-difference-between-shuddha-pandashi-saubhagya-panch) u will find the name of some scriptures that discuss mantroddhara for Shodashi. So, it depends on whether one can find texts like Gyanarnava Tantra, Sri Krama, Rudra Yamala etc online or not.

Comment: BTW if i may ask are u a Bengali?

Comment: I am from north india. Not bengali.

Comment: Ok.. So the scriptures that i've mentioned in the linked answer contains the procedure of forming several kind of Shodashi Vidyas. So, all those texts plus may be many more.

Comment: Ok.. So the scriptures that i've mentioned in the linked answer contain the procedures of forming several kinds of Shodashi Vidyas. So, the answer to ur question will be all those texts plus may be many more.

Answer (score 4):

As shown in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27478/whats-the-chanting-benefits-difference-between-shuddha-pandashi-saubhagya-panch) few such scriptures are Rudra Yamala, Siddha Yamala, Gyanarnava Tantram, Brahma Yamala etc.

If you can buy/access the books [Nitoytsava](http://www.shivashakti.com/nityot.htm) or [Brihat Tantrasara](http://www.shivashakti.com/tantrasara.htm), then also you will get to know what the Mantra actually is and how several of it's variations are formed by the Samputana method.

Regarding the greatness of the Mantra, it is already described in details in my other answer linked above.

Comment: Even though it is linked, you should add the details from the other answer. Otherwise, it will become a link only answer or a partial answer. Also, you didn't link to the answer. You linked to question.